# IBM cloud functions with Watson Conversation

Tags: node.js, watson-conversation, botkit, ibm-cloud-functions

This is my first project with Watson Conversation. I have the conversation working OK and all nodejs is being hosted on IBM Cloud. When I integrated with Facebook and Slack there is one part of the conversation that won't work - the part that makes a call to a IBM cloud function. The funny thing is it works inside Watson and on the website integration but nowhere else. I've tried botkit middleware then conversation connector (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-connector). In both cases the name of the context variable is returned instead of the value. The flow is basically a user asks where can they vote? Watson  prompts for a number saves it as an object NRN which it passes to a cloud function and defines a result variable, context.PollingStation. In a child node i return the person's info if there are registered using $PollingStation.msg since my function resolves{msg:output}.

Watson Conversation: Correct output from variable
Website: Correct output from variable with formatting
Slack/Facebook: Variable name

HELP!

Comment: Share the relevant parts of the code. I have a working database-driven Slackbot with Watson Conversation that successfully returns data.

Comment: BTW: This is where I collect tips & tricks around processing context variables: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables